# iptables: download quota per mac address for all hosts

Tags: iptables, router, tc

On a Linux router, how to setup download quotas for all hosts?

This is for a shared wifi network with many guests:

- Each guest should start with a 150 Mb download quota and no restriction
- Once quota is reached download speed should be limited to 50 k/s
- Filtering must be based on mac address, IP addresses may change with dhcp.

[Gargoyle](https://www.gargoyle-router.com) router implements something like this, unfortunately using gargoyle is not an option here, I need to do it with tc and iptables.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/358160/178267) is a good starting point:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.2 -m quota --quota 13958643712 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:12
```

Making it use mac addresses instead of IP is easy, however it requires the addresses to be known in advance, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research here's what I found:

First, some configuration:

```
# download quota (Mb)
dl_quota_mb=150
dl_quota=$(($dl_quota_mb * 1024 * 1024))

# max speed once overquota (k/s)
dl_cap_kb=50
dl_cap=$(($dl_cap_kb * 8))

# wifi interface
if_lan=wlan0

# lan subnet
lan=192.168.1
```

Create tc classes for each ip to limit download speed:

```
TCA="tc class add dev $if_lan"
TQA="tc qdisc add dev $if_lan"
SFQ="sfq perturb 10"

$TQA root handle 1: htb
# over quota speed limits
for i in `seq 1 254`; do
    $TCA parent 1: classid 1:$i htb rate ${dl_cap}kbit ceil ${dl_cap}kbit prio 2
    $TQA parent 1:$i handle $i: $SFQ
done
```

Create ipset for lan ips with accounting:

```
ipset create IP_QUOTA bitmap:ip range $lan.0/24 counters
ipset add IP_QUOTA $lan.1-$lan.254
```

Classify overquota ips packets with iptables to make limits kick in:

```
IPT="iptables -t mangle"
IPT_POST="iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o $if_lan"

$IPT -N overquota
$IPT_POST -m set --match-set IP_QUOTA dst --bytes-gt $dl_quota -j overquota

# classify packets
for i in `seq 1 254`; do
    $IPT -A overquota --dst $lan.$i -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:$i
done
```

This gives us download quotas per IP address. To get download quotas per mac address, one way is to watch for mac/ip pair changes and set/reset IP counters accordingly.

I've setup a [project](http://github.com/lemonsqueeze/WifiDownloadQuotas) on github which implements the full solution for OpenWrt.

**Note:** As of June 2017, Gargoyle's download quotas are per IP address. Would be nice to implement something like this in Gargoyle eventually.